# PHP regexp find digits without quotes?

Tags: php

I need a regExp in PHP wich will find all digits but without quote wrapping for example:
find this: some text 1234 some text
but don`t touch this: some text "some text 1234 some text", 
and strings like this should be passed to: "1234" or " 123 " etc.

I have one incomplete desision:

```
preg_match_all('/\b\d+\b/', $str, $matches);
```

I`ve also tried something like this [^\"|\']+ but it didn`t work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP assertions:

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

```
preg_match_all("/\d+(?!')/s", $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Thx, at least U gave me the way to look, I remember that solved that problem 2-3 years ago, but now refreshing the memory - thx, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if it can be done with simple RE, but you can achieve this in two steps.

1) filter out all quoted strings like

```
$filtered = preg_replace('/"[^"]+"/', '', $str)
```

2) apply your regexp on result

```
preg_match_all('/\b\d+\b/', $filtered, $matches);
```

If your text is not huge or complicated, it should be fine (depends on memory size)

Comment: I don`t need to replace quotes with spaces - I need one regExp that solves the problem.

Comment: What for? If you only need to get those numbers (which are not inside quotes), then this solution is easy and works exactly this way: `$str = 'some "text 1234" lorem  542  2342 "ispum 6" 43';` returns  `542, 2342, 43`

Comment: Because You could read closely and recognize that I need the text will be immutable with quotes and eather digits are not wrapped in quotes where found. Is that clear? In other words - find digits, but not in quotes and leave the quotes with digits and other stuff in there without changes.